# How to redirect to another page without express

Tags: node.js, http, redirect

The server's code is here:https://github.com/Bubblery/server.js/blob/master/.gitignore

And at the 103. I have a condition. Then i want to redirect another page. Just like the "index.html".

Answer (score 0):

You're in a scope where `req` and `res` is available, so just end it and output a redirect header

```
if (results.length > 0) {
    results.forEach(function (key) {
        if (key.password != userParsed.password) {
            res.writeHead(301, {
                'Location': 'your/path/file.html'
            });
            res.end();
        } else {
            console.log(key.password);
        }
    });
}
```